# how to add tanh to one embedding layer in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I wanted to add one tanh layer to embedding layer with keras functional api:

```
x=layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 8, input_length=max_length)(input)
output=keras.activations.tanh(x)

model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(data, labels)
```

but system told me I must use keras layers ,not tensor. I searched a lot keras tutorials. There is only one way to solve this problem:

```
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
```

but it is Sequential model which I don't want to use.Is there some ways to solve this with functional api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the functional api it's almost the same as the Sequential model:

```
output = Activation('tanh')(x)
```